# Swift 3: Search Bar System Group Container Debugger Output

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

I am working on an iOS app  that makes use of a handful of search bars. Whenever the user taps on any of the search bars, i get the output seen below in my debugger:

```
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Is this something i should be concerned about, and if so, is there a fix for it?

**Edit - One of such ViewControllers can be seen below:**

```
FollowersViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var followersConstant = User.generateUserArray() 
    var followers = [User]()
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false

        followers = followersConstant
    }

    //MARK: searchBar functions
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            followers = followersConstant
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            filterTableView(text: searchText)
        }
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func filterTableView (text: String) {
        followers = followersConstant.filter { (name) -> Bool in
            return (name.userName?.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()))!
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you post your code or a [mcve] ?